# Avoiding line break when starting align

Tags: align

I have a problem with the align enviornment within a list. 
Align always starts in a new line. Is there a possibility to avoid that?

In the code below the formula starts one line below the a). I want it to start in the same line as I would use simple inline math mode. I tried to shift it with \vspace but that seems not to work. Can anybody help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[a)] 
\begin{align*}  
 y &= a+bx
\end{align*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the real equation is so simple, as you write in MWE, what then you don't wirite as in-line math, something like `item[a)] $y=ax+b$`. And for enumerate text don't use `itemize` environment, use `enumerate` instead it ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed it to enumerate. I did not use inline math mode since I wanted to aline more equations and therefore use something like align.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aligned` environment should do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[a)]
        $ \begin{aligned}[t]
        y &= a+bx\\z & = cx + d
  \end{aligned} $
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]